# Does the aiohttp Python library in Windows support HTTPS?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-asyncio

When I make an HTTPS request using the aiohttp library with asyncio and Python 3.4 in Windows 7, the request fails with a NotImplementedError in the _make_ssl_transport function in base_events.py as shown in the traceback.

On Windows, I use the ProactorEventLoop. I think you have to use that one to get asyncio to work. I tried the same request in a Debian 7 VM with a compiled version of Python 3.4, and the same request works. I don't use the ProactorEventLoop in Debian, just the default though.

Any ideas or workarounds? Or, should I give up with aiohttp HTTPS on Windows for now? I am not able to use Linux for this project, needs to be on Windows.

Comment: you need `ProactorEventLoop()` to [read output from subprocesses' pipes using `asyncio`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20697159/4279). Try the default loop (remove set_event_loop() calls) to make https requests instead.

Comment: That seems to work, but the only problem is that when I close the loop, I always get an exception, even when there are not more pending tasks.

Comment: it just means that there are more than one issue in your code. Create a [minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [post it as a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - your earlier comment about using the default event loop works for HTTPS on Windows, thanks. The ProactorEventLoop just does not seem to work. I guess I need 2 loops if running shell commands and HTTP(S) request in Python on Windows.

Comment: you could [post your comment as an answer and accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer): 1. ProactorEventLoop is incompatible with SSL 2. The default loop supports SSL on Windows and by extension aiohttp should also work with https on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As jfs and OP observe,

1. ProactorEventLoop is incompatible with SSL, and
2. The default loop supports SSL on Windows. By extension aiohttp should also work with https on Windows.